# How to get current timestamp in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timestamp

I am trying to query a group of IDs created in the last 30 days in an AWS Lambda function written in python. I need the lambda to be able to generate a current timestamp in this format:  2021-05-22T00:00:00. How can I get this timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='seconds')
'2021-06-23T17:19:53'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the lambda request time epoch in `requestTimeEpoch`. Just take care, the value is in milliseconds.

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(event['requestContext']['requestTimeEpoch'] / 1000)
```